# Many users are not formatting images properly. What to do?

Tags: discussion, markdown, image

I've been editing posts on the Ask Ubuntu website for a couple of weeks and I've found that there more than a hundred posts where images are not formatted properly. Most of the users are either forgetting to add the *exclamation mark* or maybe deleted the *exclamation mark* before posting the question/answer. What can Ask Ubuntu do to tackle this issue? Can a new badge be awarded to a user when he/she formats a image properly (for the first time)? Or should Ask Ubuntu not let the user post the question/answer until they format the image properly?

Also one more thing to note is that many users are not typing the image descriptions either. To find out the posts where images are not formatted peoperly, I type *enter image description here* in the search box. There are many results and some are even closed/duplicate. I've edited some closed/duplicate questions in the past. But after a couple of days(after editing the question), the post gets removed and I lose the reputation gained earlier. In these kinda situations I'm confused as to whether I must edit the post in the first place because anyway it might mostly be removed. Or am I mistaken?

I do understand that other users in the community can edit the post but what I'm trying to say is, what if we never let the post containing an improperly formatted image be published until the user properly formats it. Is this a bad or good idea?

Answer (score 17):

> Most of the users are either forgetting to add the *exclamation mark* or maybe deleted the *exclamation mark* before posting the question/answer.

That's not what happens (at least not in most cases); new users *are not allowed* to post images on some sites: [Which SE sites require 10 reputation points to post images?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258875/295232) because it [has led to abuse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286118/295232) in the past.

Those posts usually end up in the [First Posts review queue](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/1078589); users there are expected (if the question is good enough for the site) to edit the post and inline the images (and crop/resize them if necessary). Once a new user receives their first upvote, they already have enough reputation to properly post images.

Comment: Let's say that the person who reviewed the question didn't edit the post and the the question got an upvote. Why can't AskUbuntu remind the user to edit their post and format image properly?

Comment: What about the image description? I strongly feel that AskUbuntu can make it mandatory to type an image description and user reputation has nothing to do with image description I guess.

Comment: +1, and +10 if I could for **[reviewers of First Posts] are expected to [evaluate whether the post is good enough for the site and] edit the post and inline the images**. Thank you, thank you

Comment: @technastic_tc see [Could image description be input in the Add Image dialog box while uploading images?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231949/295232) and related posts. As for your suggestion in the first comment, I think that could help, it's just not implemented that way. And most new users don't care about this, as long as they get an answer they're happy. It's the more experienced users like you who care about the site itself in the long run.