# Why are new users not allowed to post images below 10 reputation?

Tags: support, image

I am somewhat of an active user of Ask Ubuntu. As I've been editing other peoples' posts (to improve them or something else) I've noticed a pattern... Users with below a 100 reputation used links to post images and those with above a 100 reputation posted visible images.

Out of curiosity, I created an alt account (don't worry, I deleted it afterwards) and made a question draft, and dragged a picture... it said that you can only post images above 10 reputation... and there was my answer for why there was this pattern (the users who got 11-99 reputation must have stuck with it). But what is the reason for this?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19282.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Many users are not formatting images properly. What to do?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19282/many-users-are-not-formatting-images-properly-what-to-do)

Comment: imho, it's -30%-40% Match so it's not a duplicate

Comment: I don't find that question to be a duplicate. That question's _answer_ is "new users are not allowed to post images". While this question is asking clarification about that answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is indeed a bit of a pain, but there is an important reason: to prevent spammers from posting inappropriate images.

On the plus side, people who want to gain reputation to access features like voting and commenting can clock up points by suggesting edits to format images :)

Comment: Haha, like I do... Thanks for your answer +1.

Comment: :) thanks, glad it helped!

Comment: And one more thing @Zanna, there is a consequence for this fix... Won't the people at AU get free reputation by editing them and the edit queue be bigger than normal?

Comment: Like seriously, more than half of my reputation is because of this....

Comment: @RishonJR We want it to be easy to gain a little rep, because we want people who are interested in the site to be able to access basic moderation features - to vote, flag, comment, post on meta and chat, etc. It's not so easy to gain a lot of rep. There's actually a cap on reputation you can earn from suggesting edits - it's 1000 points.

Comment: Overall or yearly?

Comment: @RishonJR It is overall. But I am not sure whether it is 1000 points or 2000 points. But anyway, once you cross that much reputation, then you will not anymore earn points by suggesting edits.

Comment: @RishonJR the rep you can earn all time from suggesting edits is 1000. If posts you earned rep from suggesting edits to are deleted, you lose the rep, so you can get it back by suggesting again. Once you reach 2000 reputation, you can edit without review and approve suggested edits by others, and neither of these activities contribute to your reputation. See the the full guide [here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Comment: Okay, thanks...